ggplot: combine multiple panel with same size of the plot region
I am attempting to combine three plots into three panels for one figure. Since the three panels share the same data on the x-axis, I would like to remove the x-axis and labels for plots 1 and 2. However, I have encountered an issue where the plot region for plots 1 and 2 is much larger than that for plot 3. How can I fix this?
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Generate synthetic data
set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10))

# Create plots
p1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + labs(title = "Plot 1")
p2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + labs(title = "Plot 2")
p3 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + labs(title = "Plot 3")

# Arrange plots using ggarrange
ggarrange(
  p1 + rremove(c("x.text")) + rremove("xlab"),
  p2 + rremove("x.text") + rremove("xlab"),
  p3,
  labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
  common.legend = TRUE,
  legend = "bottom",
  nrow = 3
)



You could use the facet_ functions in ggplot2
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) %>% mutate(facet = "A")
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) %>% mutate(facet = "B")
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)) %>% mutate(facet = "C")

df <-
  bind_rows(df1,df2,df3)

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(facet),ncol = 1)+
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0,'lines'))



The figure regions for the first two plots are bigger (taller) because you removed the x-axis. ggplot automacatically adjusts the plot heights so that white space (the empty area between plots) is minimised.
You can manually adjust the heights of the 3 plots as follows:
ggarrange(
  p1 + rremove(c("x.text")) + rremove("xlab"),
  p2 + rremove("x.text") + rremove("xlab"),
  p3,
  labels = c("A", "B", "C"),
  nrow = 3,
  heights = c(1, 1, 1.25) # <- Make the third one 25% taller than the others.
)


The 25% was trial and error since there is no easy way to determine the best value until the plot is created.
